# emit_signal: Error calling method from signal 'animation_finished': 'set': Method expected 2 arguments, but called with 3

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to reset the value of a variable after the animation is complete like this:

```
extends Node2D

var testing=false

func _ready():
    var ani_player=$AnimationPlayer
    ani_player.play("ani_2")
    ani_player.connect("animation_finished",self,"set",["testing",false])
```

but for some reason it gives the error:

> E 0:00:00.479   emit_signal: Error calling method from signal
> 'animation_finished': 'Node2D(Main.gd)::set': Method expected 2
> arguments, but called with 3..   <C++ Source>  core/object.cpp:1242 @
> emit_signal()

which makes no sense I'm passing 2 variables `["testing",false]` why does it keeping getting a third one?
am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables you bind are passed in addition to the ones that the signal passes… And [`animation_finished`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animationplayer.html?highlight=animation_finished#class-animationplayer-signal-animation-finished) passes the name of the animation. So the method you are calling (`set`) would actually get three arguments. To deal with that make and extra method - which ignores the first parameter - and connect to it instead.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Theraot 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74817657/15182215) here's what I did:

```
extends Node2D

var testing=false

func animation_finished_callback(var _extra, var new_val):
    testing=new_val

func _ready():
    var ani_player=$AnimationPlayer
    ani_player.play("ani_2")
    ani_player.connect("animation_finished",self,"animation_finished_callback",[false],CONNECT_ONESHOT)
```